# tkinter radiobutton value no pass to label, remain at initial value

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I try to display the current variable for the radio button but it seems remain at the initial value which is zero.

my code was as below:

```
single_magnet_plot_style=IntVar(value=0)
```

Radio Button variable assignment:

```
scatter_rbtn=Radiobutton(window, text="Scatter Plot", variable=single_magnet_plot_style,value=1)
scatter_rbtn.place(relx=0.4,y=600)
        
line_rbtn=Radiobutton(window, text="Line Plot", variable=single_magnet_plot_style,value=2)
line_rbtn.place(relx=0.6, y=600)
```

label display:

```
new_label=Label(window, text=single_magnet_plot_style.get(), fg='red', font=("Helvetica", 13))
new_label.place(relx=0.5, y=550,anchor=CENTER)
```

at my window, the label constantly stay at value 0.

[image]

Any advice to return the `new_label` from the radio button value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use option `textvariable` instead of `text` if you want the label be updated whenever the selection of radiobuttons is changed:

```py
new_label=Label(window, textvariable=single_magnet_plot_style, fg='red', font=("Helvetica", 13))
```